# How can I use XSLT to permutate a node hierarchy?

Tags: xslt

First of all: I'm a total beginner with `XSLT`. In a project we are synthesizing tree transformations in a more abstract manner. For a proof of concept I am trying to extend the domain also to simple `XSLT`.

But let's just look at one example, I have several leaves in my XML document, like in here:

```
<input>
       <a>
         <b>
           <c>Foo </c>
           <c>Bar </c>
         </b>
       </a>
       <x>
         <y>
           <z>Foobar </z>
         </y>
       </x>
</input>
```

For what I want to do, it's easier to look at the paths.
`a/b/c/Foo`, `a/b/c/Bar`, `/x/y/z/Foobar`

What I want to do is to change the hierarchy based on the index in the path. For example I want to first have it in the order: third level, first level, second level. For the paths mentioned above: `c/a/b/Foo`, `/c/a/b/Bar`, `/z/x/y/Foobar`.

My approach looked like this:

```
<xsl:template name="leaf">
  <xsl:copy>
        <!-- copy attributes-->                                   
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />                                  
        <!-- take another level-->
        <xsl:copy select="../"/>
    </xsl:copy>                     
</xsl:template>
```

But apparently when I'm in a `<copy>` I cannot use "../" anymore to get the parent element. I'm looking for any solution to get those kind of transformations. Either by using a completely different (my perspective on XSLT is really narrow) or by tweaking my approach.

#### Desired output:

```
<output>
    <c>
        <a>
            <b>Bar</b>
        </a>
    </c>
    <c>
        <a>
            <b>Foo</b>
        </a>
    </c>
    <z>
        <x>
            <y>Foobar</y>
        <x>
    <z>    
</output>
```

#### Additional information

- the input XML has always depth 3 (counted without the )

#### Second example

```
<input>
    <one>
        <two>
            <three>
                bla
            </three>
        </two>
        <two>
            <three>
                blub
            </three>
        </two>
    </one>
</input>

<output>
    <three>
        <one>
            <second>bla</second>
        </one>
        <one>
            <second>blub</second>
        </one>
    </three>
</output>
```

I'm still not sure if I made clear what transformation I want to achieve. Maybe this idea would help: Imagine that I totally decompose the input XML: for every leaf consider the leaf itself and the path to the leaf and then just transform the path according to the rule (third, first, second).

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please post the expected output of the transformation. Note that an XML document must have a single root element. Your sample doesn't, and I am having difficulty understanding how you can switch the hierarchy around and still end up with a well-formed XML.

Comment: Please make your input a valid XML. Without the root element in your input the numbering of levels doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You've given one input and one output. In some cases that's enough to infer what the transformation should do given ANY input. In this case, sorry, it's not. I have no idea what your transformation should produce for some input that differs even slightly from your example.

Comment: "*just transform the path according to the rule (third, first, second).*" Where will this rule be? Should it be hard-coded into the stylesheet?

Comment: @michael.hor257k. Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very elegant approach, but it works:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/*/text()"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:element name="{name(ancestor::*[1])}">
        <xsl:element name="{name(ancestor::*[3])}">
            <xsl:element name="{name(ancestor::*[2])}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. this is exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: I'm wondering how I could extend this solution apply to variable depth. For example, let's say the "rule" is "2,1,3:n -1",  meaning that leaves like /a/b/c/d/e/ become /b/a/c/d/ or /a/b/c/d/e/f/g becomes /b/a/c/d/e/f. (I'm new to SO, so I'm not sure if is it better to open a new question for this?)

Comment: There are two possible scenarios here, depending on how you want to handle branching beyond the levels that you handle explicitly.

Comment: I would like to continue this comment-thread as a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631487/how-can-i-use-xslt-to-permutate-a-node-hierarchy-part-2).